# PHPBB validate_data giving me a server error

Tags: php, validation, phpbb

I'm sure this will be a very simple issue to solve but I can't get my head around what's going wrong.

I have the following code when the form is submitted.

```
$error = array();

  $data = array(
    'recipe_name'      => utf8_normalize_nfc(request_var('recipe_name', '', true)),
    'recipe_desc'        => utf8_normalize_nfc(request_var('recipe_desc', '', true)),
  );

  // Validate user input
  $validate_array = array(
     'recipe_name'         => array('string', true, 5, 25),
     'recipe_desc'         => array('string', true, 5, 25),
  );


  $error = validate_data($data, $validate_array);
```

recipe_name contains "name test"
recipe_desc contains "desc test"

When I submit the form I get a server error.

Where am I going wrong? I've searched for examples on validating data but I still can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

Adding var_dum($data) gives

array(2) { ["recipe_name"]=> string(4) "test" ["recipe_desc"]=> string(7) "testing" }

Adding var_dump($validate_array) gives

array(2) { ["recipe_name"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "string" [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(10) } ["recipe_desc"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "string" [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(25) } }

Comment: What does the error says? If it's 500 Internal Server Error, please take a look at the error log and post it here.

Comment: add `var_dump($data);` and `var_dump($validate_array);` befor your `validate_data`-Statement and look if recipe_name and recipe_desc are contains your written values and exclude your `validate_data`-Statement

Comment: Just added the dumps. Not sure where to check the error log, I'm using XAMPP 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't included the user functions page in mine, so wasn't able to access the function, hence causing the server error. Knew it had to be something simple.

```
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);
```

Adding the above fixed the problem.